# Hibernate Annotation error

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I wanted to create a simple `Hibernate` test project.
I´ve created 2 Classes , the `Main` and `Auto`.

I don't know if the code in the main class is correct because in the official hibernate how-to there are methods used that are deprecated.

When I start the program following error occurs :

```
"Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: firsthibernate.Auto"
```

I also don't really understand why in most Tutorials they say you should mark the entities of the classes you want hibernate to work with , whats the sense of that mapping files then ? :(

Would be glad if someone could help or maybe someone even has a basic little hibernate example which actually works with the newest version of eclipse and hibernate :)

Code in

[pastebin.com/KematccG](http://pastebin.com/KematccG)

greetings

Comment: Please can add the contents of your hibernate configuration file, and the two files you are mapping?

Comment: There is the old approach: mapping files with xml files, and the new approach, annotations. Now for the concrete error, would you show some code, so we can help ?

Comment: ohhhh sry i forgot to post the pastebin link , sry *facepalm*

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KematccG

Answer (score 0):

If you're using hibernate annotations you should probably be using the @Entity annotation rather than using the old .hbm mapping files.

In your hibernate configuration properties, ensure that you have the "hibernate.archive.autodetection" property set to the value "class".  This will ensure that all your @Entity classes are properly mapped.  (See the  [hibernate configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html))

Also, its hard to tell what the problem is precisely without the code and configuration!